# Transform variables based on a constant in another object

Tags: r

## My problem

I am working with two objects, structured as follows:

```
test <- structure(list(rs1_A = c(0.1, 3), rs2_B = c(0.2, 2), rs22_C = c(2,
1)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA,
-2L))
```

```
> test
# A tibble: 2 × 3
  rs1_A rs2_B rs22_C
  <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>
1   0.1   0.2      2
2   3     2        1
```

```
coeff <- structure(list(SNP_ID = c("rs1_A", "rs2_B", "rs22_C"), coeff = c(0.3,
0.1, 0.01)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA,
-3L))
```

```
> coeff
# A tibble: 3 × 2
  SNP_ID coeff
  <chr>  <dbl>
1 rs1_A   0.3
2 rs2_B   0.1
3 rs22_C  0.01
```

My code is meant to transform every variable starting with `"rs"` in `test` by multiplying it by a coefficient (stored in `coeff$coeff`), so that the final result is, e.g.

```
  rs1_A rs2_B rs22_C
1  0.03  0.02   0.02
2  0.9   0.2    0.01
```

Ideally, it should return the same result with unsorted data and with missing values in `coeff` (in which case, it should return `NA`).

## My solutions

```
library(dplyr)
```

1. Multiplying all the variables by the coefficient vector:

```
test %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(across(starts_with("rs"))*coeff$coeff)
```

```
# A tibble: 2 × 3
# Rowwise:
  rs1_A rs2_B rs22_C
  <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>
1  0.03  0.02   0.02
2  0.9   0.2    0.01
```

This approach "works" if I sort both the columns in `test` and the rows in `coeff` beforehand, but it does not handle missingness implicitly.

2. Matching column names with vector values, deriving an index value, and looking up the index value in the vector:

```
test %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(
    across(starts_with("rs"), 
    .fns = ~.x * coeff %>%
                 pull(coeff) %>% 
                 nth(which(cur_column() == pull(coeff, SNP_ID)))
    )
  )
```

```
# A tibble: 2 × 3
# Rowwise:
  rs1_A rs2_B rs22_C
  <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>
1  0.03  0.02   0.02
2  0.9   0.2    0.01
```

I like this better, as it can deal with unsorted data in `coeff`:

```
coeff2 <- structure(list(SNP_ID = c("rs22_C", "rs2_B", "rs1_A"), coeff = c(0.01,
0.1, 0.3)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA,
-3L))
```

```
> test %>% rowwise() %>% mutate(across(starts_with("rs"), .fns =~.x*coeff2 %>% pull(coeff) %>% nth(which(cur_column() == pull(coeff2, SNP_ID)))))
# A tibble: 2 × 3
# Rowwise:
  rs1_A rs2_B rs22_C
  <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>
1  0.03  0.02   0.02
2  0.9   0.2    0.01
```

3. Like `2.`, but using `base` functions for the lookup:

```
test %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(
    across(starts_with("rs"), 
          .fns = ~.x*coeff$coeff[which(cur_column() == coeff$SNP_ID)]
    )
  )
```

## What I want to improve

1. *Speed*: this works okay for 3 variables, but the lookup step in `2.` and `3.` doesn't scale well with 100k+ variables and make it slow;
2. *Handling missing data points*: this currently works if I preprocess the inputs by removing the columns that aren't matching. Not a big deal, but it would be neat to handle it;
3. *Readability*: I suspect there is going to be a more elegant way to do it in `dplyr` without all those function calls, but I can't think of any.

Do you have any suggestion on how to rewrite this?
Thank you

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I tried to add more structure to the post. Please let me know if you think it needs further improvement

Answer (score 1):

I would probably do this with pivot - join - pivot set of operations in `dplyr`.  I would pivot the `test` data longer, then left join the `coeff` data, modify the values and then pivot wider again.  This operation will be much faster than `rowwise()` operations on larger data where `rowwise()` is very slow.  This also allows you to handle the missing data problem in a couple of different ways.  Here is an example:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

test <- structure(list(rs1_A = c(0.1, 3), rs2_B = c(0.2, 2), rs22_C = c(2,
1)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA,
-2L))

coeff <- structure(list(SNP_ID = c("rs1_A", "rs2_B", "rs22_C"), coeff = c(0.3,
0.1, 0.01)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA,
-3L))
```

```r
test %>% 
  # add observation variable - makes pivot back easier
  mutate(obs = row_number()) %>% 
  # make names_to argument the same as the ID variable in coefficients
  pivot_longer(-obs, names_to="SNP_ID", values_to="val") %>% 
  # join the coefficient data - any unmatched IDs will have NA coeff values  
  left_join(coeff) %>% 
  # modify values by multiplying by coeff
  mutate(val = val*coeff) %>% 
  # remove coeff variable
  select(-coeff) %>% 
  # pivot back to original shape
  pivot_wider(names_from="SNP_ID", values_from="val")
#> Joining with `by = join_by(SNP_ID)`
#> # A tibble: 2 × 4
#>     obs rs1_A rs2_B rs22_C
#>   <int> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>
#> 1     1  0.03  0.02   0.02
#> 2     2  0.9   0.2    0.01
```

Below, I made a new dataset that has a variable that is unmatched in the `coeff` data.

```r
test2 <- structure(list(rs1_A = c(0.1, 3), rs2_B = c(0.2, 2), rs22_C = c(2,
1), rs33_D = c(.4, .6)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA,
-2L))
```

If you don't do anything, the values with missing `coeff` entries will be missing in the result.

```
test2 %>% 
  mutate(obs = row_number()) %>%
  pivot_longer(-obs, names_to="SNP_ID", values_to="val") %>% 
  left_join(coeff) %>% 
  mutate(val = val*coeff) %>% 
  select(-coeff) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from="SNP_ID", values_from="val")
#> Joining with `by = join_by(SNP_ID)`
#> # A tibble: 2 × 5
#>     obs rs1_A rs2_B rs22_C rs33_D
#>   <int> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
#> 1     1  0.03  0.02   0.02     NA
#> 2     2  0.9   0.2    0.01     NA
```

If you wanted the values to retain their original values rather than be missing, you could replace missing `coeff` entries with 1 as below.

```r
test2 %>% 
  mutate(obs = row_number()) %>%
  pivot_longer(-obs, names_to="SNP_ID", values_to="val") %>% 
  left_join(coeff) %>% 
  mutate(coeff= ifelse(is.na(coeff), 1, coeff), 
         val = val*coeff) %>% 
  select(-coeff) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from="SNP_ID", values_from="val")
#> Joining with `by = join_by(SNP_ID)`
#> # A tibble: 2 × 5
#>     obs rs1_A rs2_B rs22_C rs33_D
#>   <int> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
#> 1     1  0.03  0.02   0.02    0.4
#> 2     2  0.9   0.2    0.01    0.6
```

<sup>Created on 2023-08-10 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

In terms of speed, I made a dataset with 100 observations and 100,000 columns and a corresponding coefficient dataset.  The algorithm suggested above completed in around 3 seconds (M1 Max MacBookPro, 64GB memory).  The `rowwise()` code in your question I stopped executing at around 2 minutes.  Here's the test:

```r
large <- matrix(runif(100000*100, 0, 0), ncol=100000)
colnames(large) <- paste0("r_V", 1:100000)
large <- as.data.frame(large)

coeff_l <- data.frame(SNP_ID = paste0("r_V", 1:100000), 
                      coeff = runif(100000, 1, 3))

system.time({
out <- large %>% 
  mutate(obs = row_number()) %>%
  pivot_longer(-obs, names_to="SNP_ID", values_to="val") %>% 
  left_join(coeff_l) %>% 
  mutate(val = val*coeff) %>% 
  select(-coeff) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from="SNP_ID", values_from="val")
})
# Joining with `by = join_by(SNP_ID)`
#    user  system elapsed 
#   3.210   0.369   3.577
```

```r
system.time({
out <- large %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(
    across(starts_with("r"), 
           .fns = ~.x * coeff_l %>%
             pull(coeff) %>% 
             nth(which(cur_column() == pull(coeff_l, SNP_ID)))
    )
  )
})
```